# prove that there is only one plane that includes the point $P$ and parallel to $(Q)$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Problem :

If a point P doesnt lie on the plane $(Q)$

how to prove that there is only one

plane that includes the point $P$ and

parallel to $(Q)$ ?

I think use Linear correlation of vectors

but how I don't know ?

Calle $\vec{n}$ the vector normal of

plan $(Q)$ but how ? I complete

I already to see your solution !

Comment: Hint: $P$ and $Q$ have the same normal vector, say $(a,b,c)$, so that the equations of $P$ and $Q$ are $ax+by+cz=\langle \textrm{constant}\rangle$ for some pair of constants.

Comment: @rogerl can you complete your idea ??

Comment: I think you should be able to take it from here. If you can't, you should modify your question to show your work. Then perhaps someone can help you tie up any loose ends.

Answer (score 0):

We want to give a (very simple) purely affine proof, without use of coordinates.

Let $\mathbb A$ denote an affine space with vector space associated $E$. If $P\in \mathbb A$, a (affine) plane $\pi$ of $\mathbb A$ through $P$ is a subspace of $\;\mathbb A\;$ of the form

$$ \pi = P + F $$

where $F$ is a vector subspace of $\;E\;$ with $\dim(F)=2$. Two planes

$$ P+F, \quad P'+F' $$

are parallel if and only if, by definition:

$$ F \subseteq F' \text{$\;\;$ or $\;\;$} F' \subseteq F $$

and therefore iff $\;F=F'$, since $\;\dim(F)=\dim(F')$.

We conclude that a plane through $P$ parallel to a given plane $Q+F$ is necessarily of the form $P+F$, what proves the existence and uniqueness.

Note that the hypothesis $P\notin Q+F$ was not used. The result is as such even if $P$ lies on the given plane $Q+F$. In that case we actually have

$$ P+F = Q + (P-Q) + F = Q + F $$

being $P-Q \in F$.